# Metric-like families of relations

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, relations

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and to start with, let us consider a relation $\leq$ on $X$ (that is $\leq$ is a subset of $X^2$) which is reflexive and transitive. such a relation is called a preorder. Now, let us consider a similar object - a family of relations $\leq^\delta$ parametrized by $\delta\in[0,\infty)$ that satisfy the following properties:

1. $x\leq^0 x$ for any $x\in X$,
2. if $x\leq^\delta y$ and $y\leq^{\epsilon} z$ then $x\leq^{\delta+\epsilon} z$ for any $x,y,z\in X$.

The first condition is obviously reflexivity, whereas the second can be understood as "approximate transitivity". It reminds of the triangular inequality. In fact, the function
$$
  d(x,y):=\inf\{\delta>0:x\leq^\delta y \text{ and }y\leq^\delta x\}
$$
can be shown to be a pseudo-metric (a metric that can be zero outside of the diagonal). Is there any special name for the family $\leq^\delta$, or for its symmetrization $\approx^\delta$ where
$$
  x\approx^\delta y \iff x\leq^\delta y \text{ and }y\leq^\delta x.
$$
Let me also mention that $\leq^0$ alone is a pre-order.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but this is how you can define the Hausdorff distance. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

Comment: @Plop: I guess, the only similarity here comes from the fact that the Hausdorff metric is defined using non-symmetric [quasimetrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics), however this is not of an importance here. I guess, relations $\approx%\delta$ are more related to entourages in the framework of [uniform spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear : for $A$ and $B$ parts of a metric space, if we say that $A \leq^{\delta} B$ if $\forall x \in A$, $d(x,B) \leq \delta$, then $(\leq^\delta)_{\delta \in [0,+\infty[}$ verifies the properties that you asked. I was just saying that your idea has already been formulated, so it has probably a name. So my answer to your question is "Yes, probably". And I don't know if it helps :)